# jquery start scroll at bottom when div is hidden?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want all .list_messages div start scroll at the bottom ! I tried with that jquery but it's work only on when the div is show , how can i make it work even if the div is hidden ?

```
<div id="incidence_5" class="discussion  col-md-8" data="5" style="">

<div id="list_messages5" class="list_messages" colspan="7" 
style="max-
height: 653px;">

<div id="incidence_4" class="discussion  col-md-8" data="4" 
style="display: none;">

<div id="list_messages4" class="list_messages" colspan="7" 
style="max-height: 653px;">



$(document).ready(function() {



var b= $(window).height();
var c= $('.tbl-header').height();
    $(".list_messages").css("max-height",b - 60);



$(".discussion").each(function(){
  var testdata = $(this).attr('data')
// $(this).val(testdata);
$('#list_messages'+testdata).scrollTop($('#list_messages'+testdata)[0].scrollHeight);   
console.log(testdata);
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way is to change your hiding mechanism from `display` to `visibility`:

```
<div id="incidence_4" class="discussion  col-md-8" data="4" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

This makes the element hidden, but the element still maintains its layout in the DOM.

Comment: yes but the thing i want the div to stay at the same place ! like when i click on one all are hidden but with visibility there is blank before

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: i want the div .discussion to always stay at the same place ! when i use display none it work cause the displayed div replace the hidden div but with visibility they always here even without being visible